# Iterate through a listView in android to make check boxes visible in front of each item

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I used the android notepad tutorial code to start with. In my notes_row.xml, I have a textview to display title of note, and a check box that is hidden initially by android:visibility="gone"

I want that when the user opens options menu and click on Mark, the check boxes in front of each item in the list should become visible. However, when I click on Mark in emulator, the check box of only the first note becomes visible. So, I want to iterate through the whole list, and setVisibility(0) so that all check boxes are visible. I am a beginner, so please answer in detail. Thanks in advance.

My code snippet:

```
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
    case INSERT_ID:
        createNote();
        return true;
    case MARK_ID:
                // only first item check box appears with following 2 lines:
                    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
                    checkBox.setVisibility(0);

                /* tried the following, but no chekbox appears with this:   
        Cursor c = mDbHelper.fetchAllNotes();
        c.moveToPosition(0);
        while(c.isAfterLast()){
            CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
            checkBox.setVisibility(0);
            c.moveToNext();
        }
                 */
        return true;
}
```

**My new code after reading the answers, still only the first item's check box appears:**

```
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
    case INSERT_ID:
        createNote();
        return true;
    case MARK_ID:
        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        String[] lvItems = new String[]{NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE};
        MyAdapter arrAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, lvItems);
        arrAdapter.toggleCheckBoxVisibility(checkBox);
        arrAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    return true;
    return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
             }
```

**Here is my adapter:**

```
private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            String[] objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.notes_row, parent, false);
        //String[] from = new String[]{NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE};
        return row;
        //return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    public boolean toggleCheckBoxVisibility(CheckBox checkBox){
        checkBox.setVisibility(0);
        super.notifyDataSetChanged();
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: which adapter you are suing for displaying individual item in list

Comment: i am using:
    Cursor notesCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllNotes();
  startManagingCursor(notesCursor);

  // Create an array to specify the fields we want to display in the list (only TITLE)
  String[] from = new String[]{NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE};

  // and an array of the fields we want to bind those fields to (in this case just text1)
  int[] to = new int[]{R.id.textView1};

  // Now create a simple cursor adapter and set it to display
  SimpleCursorAdapter notes = 
    new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.notes_row, notesCursor, from, to);
  setListAdapter(notes);
}

Answer (score 0):

1. Take your list adapter
2. Iterate through the list items' views using getView (or similar)
3. For each view you fetch do v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)

This is roughly what you have to do to interact with each view of your list

EDIT: more specifically:
inside your activity main thread

```
MyAdapter a= (MyAdapter) this.getArrayAdapter(); 
//count how many views you have to iterate and build a for loop accordingly
for(...){
    View v = a.getView(/*based on the for index position */).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) 
//Do something else with the view if you want...
```

This solution supposes that you already created and associated with your activity an array adapter.

Comment: Please elaborate step 2!! that's what my question is!
Thanks.

Comment: inside your activity main thread, for example:

    MyAdapter a= (MyAdapter) this.getArrayAdapter();

    //count how many views you have to iterate and build a for loop accordingly

    View v = a.getView(/*based on the for index position */).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)

    //Do something else with the view if you want...

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter create a method to set a boolean flag for the visibility. On button click call the method and set the flag to true. Then use `notifyDataSetChanged()` to update your list.
In your getView method you can then set the visibility of your checkbox to the value in the boolean flag.

Comment: I did this, but still only the first item's check box appears. Please see the edits in the question. I can email you the complete project if you want. Thanks.

Comment: You misunderstood my approach - the method in the adapter should be:
public void toggleCheckBoxVisibility(boolean visibility){
checkboxVisibility = visibility;
notifyDataSetChanged();
}

In your getView you then use:
CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
checkBox.setVisibility(checkboxVisibility ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
In your class's write this code:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    ArrayAdapter<String> araAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),             

    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, xmlList);
    listView_xml.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    listView_xml.setAdapter(araAdapter);
}
```

xmlList is what the data ur saving or your string[] array. listview_xml is your listview's name.
[Go through this tutorial implementing multiple check boxes](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-listview-multiple-choice-example)